# Angular 5: Resolve guard cancels ongoing navigation

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I have the following route:

```
{
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    resolve: {
        profile : ProfileResolve,
    }
}
```

and this is my resolver code:

```
public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
               state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<UserProfile | number> {

    const userid = this.auth.getUserId();
    return this.ps.getProfile(userid).take(1).map(
        profile => profile).catch(errorCode => Observable.of(errorCode));
}
```

My AuthGuard, after a successful authentication, calls `router.navigate(['/profile'])` to resume navigation, and at this point I see the resolver guard is activated.
But the issue is that the resolver seems to cause the navigation to get canceled. When I turn on the router tracer I see that the resolution happens (and I've verified the resolved data is correct) but then navigation is cancelled even if data is resolved, as shown in the screenshot. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have checked `Authguard`'s result?

Comment: @Pengyy, yes, I'm almost certain the issue is not the AuthGurd. In fact, when I comment out ResolveGuard the issue goes away, conforming my suspicion that it's the ResolveGuard that's at fault.

Comment: thanks for the response. That sounds wired. Can you reproduce your scenario with a online demo?